# Unix command to find a word in file

Tags: grep

We are having a shell script. In the shell script, we want to find out whether the file `file.log` has word as `MB`. If so, store it to variable `v_name` in the shell script, if no such word is there, then `v_name` should be empty.

*Note:* The `file.log` will contain at most one `MB` word.

Comment: This is pretty basic stuff to do. What have you tried? Were did it go wrong? BTW. A Google search for "Unix command to find a word in file" turns up a number of results.

Comment: please edit your question and add a small sample of the input and the expected output.

Comment: If you don't need an array, please could you give an excerpt of your input and disired output?

Comment: would/could the MB *value* be on a separate line from the "MB" *string*?

Answer (score 3):

If `file.log` contains the string `MB`, then assign the text `MB` to the variable `v_name`:

```
grep -q MB file.log && v_name=MB
```

Ref: [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/grep) for grep

Comment: Hi,My file 'file.log' data is 'WRITE_LOG: This is log. File
 Size: 67.61 MB'. So I want the value 67.61 to the variable 'v_name'. The end of file is always with 'MB'. So, I want the value 67.61 in 'v_name' variable (this value will vary)

Comment: I am not sure whether this will work only with grep command or not, but I want the value to be placed in variable

Comment: You should be clearer in your question what you want to have. You said "find out whether the file file.log has word as MB. If so, store it to variable v_name". Show some sample input (could values be 1,234.55789 MB?)

Answer (score 0):

An unix command to find a word in files is

`grep`

```
$ man grep | grep -A 5 DESCRIPTION
DESCRIPTION
   grep  searches the named input FILEs (or standard input if no files are named, or if a single hyphen-minus (-) is given as file name) for lines containing a
   match to the given PATTERN.  By default, grep prints the matching lines.

   In addition, three variant programs egrep, fgrep and rgrep are available.  egrep is the same as grep -E.  fgrep is the same as grep -F.  rgrep is  the  same
   as grep -r.  Direct invocation as either egrep or fgrep is deprecated, but is provided to allow historical applications that rely on them to run unmodified.
```

Comment: `grep -l "find this"  *`  will return file names having the string `find this` in them.  using the `i` option such as `grep -li mb *.txt` will return the file names that have string `mb` or `MB` or `Mb` or `mB`, for all `*.txt` files in current directory.

Comment: this doesn't address the original, unclear, question of assigning anything to a variable, much less the apparent goal of assigning the MB *value* to a variable.

Comment: @ron Of course! That's why I have gave the hint with `man grep`, because OP has asked for an unix command to find a word in file.

Comment: @JeffSchaller Answer the effort, not the effort of an answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
v_name=$(grep -P "\d+\.\d+ MB")
```

gives your variable e.g. "92.29 MB"

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

# $1 = pattern
# $2 = file name to search in
# did not write or test script to handle wild cards in $2

# -i option in grep is case insensitive, use just -l if you care about case

vname=`grep -li $1 $2`

if [ -z "$vname" ]; then
   echo "vname is empty"
else
   echo "vname is " $vname
   # set vname to pattern searched for
   vname=$1
   echo "vname is " $vname
fi
```